# Caching programmatically added 301s to ASP.NET webform site

Tags: asp.net, caching, redirect, webforms

I'm looking into methods and techniques of programmatically adding 301s to a ASP.NET webforms site.

A clients site is being optimised for SEO and we're trying to avoid the usual "send us a list of 301s and we'll add them to the site" every time they make a change. Previously we've been provided a list of 301s and have added them to global.asax (on request) or web.config and let .NET do the rest.

I was wondering if there is any accepted "best" way to do dynamic 301s.

Persisting the redirects I can do in XML/SQL no problem. I'm guessing though there would be a performance hit if we read xml/queried the DB on every request.

I could of course cache them - but where? Application context would seem the obvious place but I'm wary of saving hundreds of 301s in Application.
Considering how 301 happy SEO experts can get I don't want them to add thousands then wonder why the server fell over. Is this a valid concern?
Or in Cache? Has the advantage of letting .NET manage memory so they will be cleared if resources become scarce and can always be recreated. Does it offer any advantage over Application though?

I could add a config xml file, update this via the CMS and reference it from the web.config - would this work or would the site need to be recycled to pick up changes?

To clarify, storing and executing the 301s is not an issue. I'm after a method of checking 301s and redirecting that will be quick without impacting the users experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about only processing the list when a 404 is detected, by hooking up the Application_Error event? This way standard requests are processed without any additional load but the 404's are still redirected when they occur.

http://cypressnorth.com/downloads/how-to-create-multiple-301-redirect-urls-in-asp-net-mvc/

(I know this is an old question but I'm just working through the same problem).

Comment: It may be old but it's still relevant. I hadn't thought of adding a 301 lookup on a 404. Nice one.